# MacBookPro trackpad is on crack!

Tags: trackpad

It's as if an alien entity has commandeered the trackpad, and it highlights things when it has not been asked to do so; the mouse jumps erratically all over the place, AND opens up random windows unbidden. In this state it's nearly impossible to write anything on the computer in this condition.
Guidance, anyone?
MacBook Pro
Mac OSX 10.6.8
TenQ

Comment: I have had this issue with an external trackpad and keyboard, with the end result being a key on the keyboard was stuck if I remember right it was the space bar, after much frustration I ran my had across the keyboard and this resolved the issue.

Comment: I often forget a bluetooth mouse or trackpad and find that they are in a bag or otherwise pressed when I find my main trackpad is behaving like you describe.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem with on my Retina. Rebooting and SMC reset didn't help.

Surprisingly I was able to fix it by pressing down hard in each upper corner as recommended in this Apple Communities [thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4206644). According to it the problem is due to pressure on the trackpad and pressing down resets/releases that somehow.